# Why I can call 'print' from 'eval'

Tags: python, printing, import, eval, built-in

For code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

src = """
print '!!!'
import os
"""

obj = compile(src, '', 'exec')
eval(obj, {'__builtins__': False})
```

I get output:

```
!!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 9, in <module>
    eval(obj, {'__builtins__': False})
  File "", line 3, in <module>

ImportError: __import__ not found
```

Both 'print' and 'import' are language construct. Why does 'eval' restrict using of 'import' but doesn't restrict 'print'?

P.S. I'm using python 2.6

UPDATE: Question is not "Why does import not work?" but "Why does print work?" Are there some architecture restrictions or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `__import__` method is invoked by the `import` keyword:  [python.org](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=import#__import__)

If you want to be able to import a module you need to leave the `__import__` method in the builtins:

```
src = """
print '!!!'
import os
"""

obj = compile(src, '', 'exec')
eval(obj, {'__builtins__': {'__import__':__builtins__.__import__}})
```

Comment: Question is not "Why does import not work?" but "Why does print work?"

Comment: print becomes a method in python 3k, I bet it will not work anymore :)

Answer (score 2):

In your `eval` the call to `import` is made successfully however `import` makes use of the `__import__` method in builtins which you have made unavailable in your `exec`. This is the reason why you are seeing

```
ImportError: __import__ not found
```

`print` doesn't depend on any builtins so works OK.

You could pass just `__import__` from builtins with something like:

```
eval(obj, {'__builtins__' : {'__import__' :__builtins__.__import__}})
```

Comment: Ok, but why one simple statement (like said in documentation: http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html) has appropriate builtin method, and another hasn't? Does this (architectural?) solution has any practical meaning?

Comment: `__import__` method exists so, for example, you can replace it and change the semantics of `import`. However this is better done using import hooks. See http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__ In Python 3.x `print` has been replaced with the `print()` builtin method so you would see the same behaviour with print in 3.x

Answer (score 0):

print works because you specified `'exec'` to the `compile` function call.

Answer (score 0):

`import` calls the global/builtin `__import__` function; if there isn't one to be found, `import` fails.

`print` does not rely on any globals to do its work. That is why `print` works in your example, even though you do not use the available `__builtins__`.