# Python: how do I call `print` from `eval` in a loop?

Tags: python, eval, python-2.x

When I call `print` from `eval`:

```
def printList(myList):
    maxDigits = len(str(len(myList)))
    Format = '0{0}d'.format(maxDigits)
    for i in myList:
        eval('print "#{0:' + Format + '}".format(i+1), myList[i]')
```

it gives an error:

```
    print "#{0:01d}".format(i+1), myList[i]
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried to make use of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3949812/788700), and re-wrote it:

```
def printList(myList):
    maxDigits = len(str(len(myList)))
    Format = '0{0}d'.format(maxDigits)
    for i in myList:
        obj = compile(src, '', 'exec')
        eval('print "#{0:' + Format + '}".format(i+1), myList[i]')
```

but this complains about the `i`:

```
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

P.S. I'm dealing with `python2.6`

Comment: Which version of python? Unless I'm mistaken, print syntax is different in python 3.

Comment: Why are you using eval to begin with?

Comment: Which version of python is this?

Comment: @Gerrat: I'm using `eval` because I want to substitute the format specification. See the `Format = ` string.

Comment: @Adobe:  This isn't a great use for eval (there aren't many). You can just substitute `Format` this into your string to begin with.  No need to eval it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need eval:

```
def printList(myList):
    maxDigits = len(str(len(myList)))
    str_format = '#{0:0' + str(maxDigits) + '}'
    for i, elem in enumerate(myList, 1):
        print str_format.format(i), elem
```

or, as @SvenMarnach noted, you can put even the formatting parameter into one format call:

```
def printList(myList):
    maxDigits = len(str(len(myList)))
    for i, elem in enumerate(myList, 1):
        print '#{1:0{0}} {2}'.format(maxDigits, i, elem)
```

Comment: You don't even need to build `str_format`.  `print "{0:0{1}}".format(i, maxDigits)` will just work fine.

Comment: Funny that your comment is being voted for better than my answer, although I posted it first :p

Comment: @Gandaro - and he gets one more from me (you too), because this nesting was new to me.

Answer (score 16):

You can't `eval()` a `print`: `eval()` is used to evaluate expression, and print is a statement. If you want to execute a statement, use `exec()`. Check [this question for a better explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220699/whats-the-difference-between-eval-exec-and-compile-in-python):

```
>>> exec('print "hello world"')
hello world
```

Now, you can pass your locals() variables if you want to make accessible the i in the exec:

```
>>> i = 1
>>> exec('print "hello world", i', locals())
hello world 1
```

*In addition, in the last test you wrote, you compile() in 'exec' mode, that should give you a tip :)*

Answer (score 3):

To keep your code while making it shorter and easier to understand:

```
def printList(myList):
    # int(math.log10(len(myList))+1) would be the appropriate way to do that:
    maxDigits = len(str(len(myList)))
    for i in myList:
        print "#{0:0{1}d}".format(i+1, maxDigits), myList[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplistic view is this.  Build the format separately from using it.  Avoid `eval()`.

```
    format =  "#{0:" + Format + "}"
    print format.format(i+1), myList[i]
```

Don't make things harder than they need to be.  Here's another version that builds the format in one step.

```
    format = '#{{0:0{0}d}}'.format(maxDigits)
    print format.format(i+1), myList[i]
```

Comment: ValueError: Invalid conversion specification